# Why the controller can't receive the parameter when using HttpPost request?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm running into a problem when I tried to use React MVC HttpPost action, the parameter in the controller didn't get any value, it's null when I debug this code. Could anybody please shed some light on this problem? Thanks.
Here is a part of my code:
js file:

```
postTimeToServer(difficulty) {        
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ difficulty: 'Easy' })
    };
    fetch('Top10Easy', requestOptions)
```

}

Top10Easy's controller in c# code:
[HttpPost]
public void Post(string difficulty)
{
Console.Write(difficulty);
}

in js file, I use postTimeToServer by ' this.postTimeToServer(state.difficulty) ', I supposed the parameter "difficulty" in Post method of HttpPost will get the value of state.difficulty, but it's null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] string difficulty) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but after I added "[FromBody]", the controller's Post function is not even called. Previously the Post function was called, and I verified the sender has sent out the correct value of the parameter by using fiddler, but the controller didn't get it